# getAppStandbyBucket needs unknown permission

Tags: android, android-permissions, power-management, android-9.0-pie, usagestatsmanager

While I try to get new Android 8 (or P) Application Standby Bucket using UsageStatsManager.getAppStandbyBucket, I receive this error, gave every permission possible to app, but still crashes :

> java.lang.SecurityException: MATCH_ANY_USER flag requires
>   INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS permission at
>   com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.getPackageUid:4959
>   com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$PackageManagerInternalImpl.getPackageUid:25142
>   com.android.server.usage.UsageStatsService$BinderService.getAppStandbyBucket:932
>   android.app.usage.IUsageStatsManager$Stub.onTransact:274
>   android.os.Binder.execTransact:731 : Neither user 10228 nor current
>   process has android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS.

Comment: Giving permission in the Manifest file is not the same as actually giving permission by the user. Are you certain that you are checking that the permission was granted by the user at the device level?

Comment: The documents didn't mention to ask user for permissions

Answer (score 2):

I posted the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51494512/android-p-usagestatsmanager-getappstandbybucket) some days ago, like [chrispher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5437033/chrispher) said, it's a bug, two issues has been filled in :

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111102580
- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111857669

I know that on the first [developer preview](https://www.xda-developers.com/android-p-developer-preview-1-google-pixel-xl-pixel-2-xl/), the function was working, so maybe you can download the factory image, put it on an emulator or a device and make your test, a bit of a trick but at least we can test this way...

**Edit: Good news !** https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111102580

We are good to test, the release is here !